# PHP - exit or return which is better?

Tags: php, terminate

I would like to know in the following case which is a better option:

In the PHP script, if the `$fileSize` variable is larger than 100, I stop the script;

Case I:

```
<?php
if ( $fileSize > 100 )
{
   $results['msg'] = 'fileSize is too big!';
   echo json_encode( $results );
   exit();
}
```

Case II:

```
<?php
if ( $fileSize > 100 )
{
   $results['msg'] = 'fileSize is too big!';
   exit( json_encode( $results ) );
}
```

Case III:

```
<?php
if ( $fileSize > 100 )
{
   $results['msg'] = 'fileSize is too big!';
   return( json_encode( $results ) );
}
```

Which of the three (3) options above is the best?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Since you are using `exit` and `return` within the global scope (not inside a function), then the behavior is almost the same.

The difference in this case will appear if your file is called through `include()` or `require()`. `exit` will terminate the program, while `return` will take the control back to the calling script (where `include` or `require` was called).

Answer (score 11):

I would tend to go with the `return()` method, so that other scripts can continue executing. That way, if you ever use another script to call this one, it can do error-handling to deal with the case where the file is too large, as opposed to always halting execution.

Answer (score 7):

It depends...if your script is intended to do nothing else but output a message, and you don't want the script to do anything afterwards, exit() will work. Otherwise, use return.

Answer (score 4):

Exit terminates the program like die(). [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)