# Return json on exit php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, return

I have been using `$.getJSON` in order to verify if a script has done its job properly, using `exit("{'status':true}")` (or false)  but now I need the script to return a value (or an array). I see that I can't use   `exit('{ "status": $myarray}');`. What can I use instead? I am new to php- is it possible to do something like `return '{ "status": $myarray}';` or something alike?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function:

```
json_encode($data);
```

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: And exit($data)? How will the ajax recieve the response?

Answer (score 4):

In your php, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as such:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($myarray);
    // or, `exit(json_encode($myarray))` if global scope (see *REF)
?>
```

and in your jQuery use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) normally:

```
$.getJSON("test.php",function(result){
    ...
});
```

(*) REF: [PHP - exit or return which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3484050/155813)

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json')` did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want return data just like as array or single data in json then
Try this code

In php file write like this

```
$value = 'welcome';
echo json_encode($value);exit;

or

$value = array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
print_r(json_encode($value));exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   `$jsonString = 'your json string'`
    $jsonArray = json_encode($jsonString);
    return $jsonArray
```

Comment: I think the question is about encoding not decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I will post the way I did it, seems quite simple to me now. Thank you for your answers

```
$json_array=array('status'=>$row);
exit(json_encode($json_array));
```

AJAX call:

```
   $.getJSON( "savefunctions/getVideos.php", function(response) {
                         if( response.status ) alert(response.status);
                         });
```