# Return an xml file avoiding to echo it

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I know one should not use `echo` in controllers, but I don't understand what I should use to return an xml in order to download it. Please note, *it's not a file on the server*, it's just a string:

```
public function export()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');
    $invoice = $this->Invoices->get($id, ['contain' => ['Customers', 'ItemInvoices' => ['ItemProformas' => ['ItemDeliveryNotes' => ['ItemOrders' => ['Orders' => ['Customers']]]]]]]);

    $fpr = new ExportInvoice();
    $fpr->SetInvoice($invoice);

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fpr->getFilename() . '"');

    $xml = $fpr->asXML();
    echo $xml;
}
```

it actually works as expected: the browser download a file with the given filename and its content is the `$xml` value.

But at the end of the file there are warnings about headers:

```
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/home/mark/myproject/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php line=130 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 51]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mark/myproject/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php:130) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 152]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mark/myproject/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php:130) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mark/myproject/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php:130) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
```

As far as I know this is due to the usage of `echo` in controller. It may happens there's an output before sending the header, and then the warnings.

What's the correct way to replace the `echo` function?

Comment: why you don't return the response object with the specified string instead of `echo` it?

Comment: You should place an `exit;` after the echo to avoid the execution of additional header functionality after your echo.

Comment: @hassan, `return $this->getResponse()->withStringBody($fpr->asXML());` seems to work. Is it correct?

Comment: @Marcel, it works either.

Comment: These should be answers rather comments, though...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `die()` or `exit()`

```
public function export()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');
    $invoice = $this->Invoices->get($id, ['contain' => ['Customers', 'ItemInvoices' => ['ItemProformas' => ['ItemDeliveryNotes' => ['ItemOrders' => ['Orders' => ['Customers']]]]]]]);

    $fpr = new ExportInvoice();
    $fpr->SetInvoice($invoice);

    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fpr->getFilename() . '"');
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something else to let them know they can't expect a file
        die();
    }

    die($fpr->asXML());
}
```

#### Update

Regarding the comment

Using [return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php), [exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) or [die](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is already explained in detail in this question [php-exit-or-return-which-is-better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484050/php-exit-or-return-which-is-better), [what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php)

Comment: There are so many ways to the same thing! Is there any advantages to use one instead of others?

Comment: You should never use die() or exit(). It is one of the worst code smells and makes testing this impossible. Use instead resposne object as documented (and as shown below in a different and more correct answer.

Comment: @mark I'm very thankful for your comment. Good to have learned something again!

Comment: note from moderator: if your answer is wrong, just delete it, don't copy others to make it better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just tried to make an accepted answer correct and more useful. Sorry, now I know it for the next time.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to the docs , you can use the framework for that , checkout how to [Sending a String as File](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file)

```
public function export()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');
    $invoice = $this->Invoices->get($id, ['contain' => ['Customers', 'ItemInvoices' => ['ItemProformas' => ['ItemDeliveryNotes' => ['ItemOrders' => ['Orders' => ['Customers']]]]]]]);

    $fpr = new ExportInvoice();
    $fpr->SetInvoice($invoice);

    // header('Content-type: text/xml');
    // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fpr->getFilename() . '"');

    $xml = $fpr->asXML();
    $response = $this->response;
    $response = $response->withStringBody($xml);
    // use $response->body($xml); for versions before 3.4.0
    $response = $response->withType('xml');
    $response = $response->withDownload($fpr->getFilename());
    return $response;
}
```